# Create/copy/duplicate form button in shared workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create/copy/duplicate or whatever in excel VBA in shared workbook. My goal is to create new button, when workbook is shared.

In standart worksheet mode I tried which works in standart mode, but fail in shared (VBA dont know .add method of buttons)

```
Sub copyButton3()
    Dim projectSheet As Worksheet
    Set projectSheet = Sheets("Projects")

    Dim newButton As button

    With projectSheet
      Set newButton = .Buttons("buttonToCopy").Add(10, 10, 10, 10)

     With newButton
     'some changes like name, size, caption, on action...

     End With
End Sub
```

Then I tried Duplicate method, but with similar result as with Add

```
Sub copyButton3()
    Dim projectSheet As Worksheet
    Set projectSheet = Sheets("Projects")

    Dim newButton As button

    With projectSheet
      Set newButton = .Buttons("buttonToCopy").Duplicate

     With newButton
     'some changes like name, size, caption, on action...
     End With
     End With
End Sub
```

Then I tried to use copy and paste, where i achieved some success with this. Finally, there is new button created, but I cant manipulate him, cause I can't select him. I tried assign selection to button variable, but in shared mode i'm getting `Run time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method` (in normal mode everything works like a charm).

```
Sub copyButton()
    Dim projectSheet As Worksheet
    Set projectSheet = Sheets("Projects")

    Dim newButton As Variant

    With projectSheet
        .Buttons("buttonToCopy").Copy

        .Paste

    Set newButton = Selection
        With newButton
            .Caption = "selected Button"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

So now I'm nearly out of ideas.

Is it even possible to cheat VBA to create new button in shared mode (I can create it) but to manipulate it later?

Comment: No, it's a limitation of shared workbooks - one of **many**.

Comment: @Rory ah thanks, i thought i almost got it, when i managed to copy that cursed button. And is this limitation for all components? Cant be button replaced with shape or smthing like that?

Comment: @Davesexcel i can run many of VBA code. Some must be with minor hacks or similar changes, but its posible

Comment: @Davesexcel You can *run* VBA, you can't view or alter it.

Comment: @LubošSuk No shapes won't work either. Avoid Shared Workbooks if at all possible - they are disasters waiting to happen.